# Complex jQuery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

Using jQuery templates is easy for some simple data structures.

```
<script type="jquery/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myTemplate">
  <li> ${Element} </li>
</script>

var elements = [
   { Element: "Hydrogen" },
   { Element: "Oxygen"   },
   { Element: "Nitrogen" }
];

$("#elementsPlaceholder").replaceWith($("#myTemplate").tmpl(elements));
```

But if I need a template for more complex data? Something like:

```
<script type="jquery/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myTemplate">
  <div> ${Molecule} </div>
  consists of:
  <ul>
      <li> ${Element} </li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

How can apply data to that? Is it possible? Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li> ${Element} </li>
</ul>
```

should use [{{each}}](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/)

```
<ul>
  {{each Elements}}<li>${$value.Element}</li>
</ul>
```

and then you pass in both the molecule and the elements

```
$("#elementsPlaceholder").replaceWith($("#myTemplate").tmpl({
  Molecule: ...
  Elements: [{ Element: "Hydrogen" }, ...]
}))
```

Comment: wait... I didn't get it.. could you please send me a link to an example

Comment: Ahem.... and apparently I can't have nested {{each}} calls? Or I can? UPD: Oh no... I can!... yehooo!